# Is MMC only for Enterprise MuleESB?

Tags: mule

By reading this:

"The Mule ESB management console centralizes management for all your Mule Enterprise Edition deployments, both the standalone variety and those embedded in application servers." [source](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Management+Console)

one can infer that MMC is not for Community ESB. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. In fact MMC communicate with the Mule ESB server through an agent that is available only for the enterprise version.